# Level-filled binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

To better understand recursive functions, I'm trying to create a Python script for a binary tree that  inserts values, filling levels entirely before going to the next one.

This is my tree-node implementation:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.right_child = None
        self.left_child = None
        self.parent = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
```

What I'm having problems with right now is setting the conditions for that criteria to be met.

An example: here i'm adding, in order, the following numbers: 12, 5, 18, 2, 9 , 15, 19, 13, 17. Thus, the only condition for putting stuff in the next level is that the parent one is filled.

```
  _12_______
 /          \
 5       __18_
/ \     /     \
2 9    15_   19
/   \
13  17
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
def insert(self,value):
    if(self.root==None):
            self.root=Node(value)
    else:
            self._insert(value,self.root)

def _insert(self, value, curNode):
        if(curNode.left_child==None):
                curNode.left_child=Node(value)
                curNode.left_child.parent = curNode

        elif(curNode.right_child==None):
                curNode.right_child=Node(value)    
                curNode.right_child.parent = curNode    

        else:
                self._insert(value,curNode.left_child)
```

which gives:

```
          _12_
         /    \
       __5   18
      /   \
    __2_  9
   /    \
  15_  19
 /   \
13  17
```

Thus ignoring all right children. The problem is, of course, the last `else` of my code. How can I make this consider both the left and right children of the node?

Comment: You probably should give a bit more code to help people looking to help you, so that they have a minimum example of your code to run. Your tree class would be helpful for starters.

Comment: Sure, it's the base tree-class node-class implementation. I'm writing it in the post right now. Thanks!

Comment: You say a binary tree, not a binary *search* tree, and it looks like what you're actually trying to do is make a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))-like data structure in the form of a tree. Instead of your current approach (insert at right place), a more useful approach might be "insert as a leaf somewhere, and then pivot the tree around until it's balanced". Also look into [self-balancing binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need a node structure with left and right pointers for this. Just store the whole tree in an array so that the children of the node at the index `N` are at `2*N+1` and `2*N+2`:

```
def print_tree(items, pos, level):
    if pos >= len(items):
        return
    print('.' * level, items[pos])
    print_tree(items, pos * 2 + 1, level + 1)
    print_tree(items, pos * 2 + 2, level + 1)


print_tree([12, 5, 18, 2, 9 , 15, 19, 13, 17], 0, 0)
```

prints

```
 12
. 5
.. 2
... 13
... 17
.. 9
. 18
.. 15
.. 19
```

which is what you want.

This is called a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).

If you're looking for a *search tree* (one that maintains the order of values), and want to keep it balanced, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Answer (score 0):

[georg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56795248/1782792) is the smart way to represent this. However, if you are interested in how you would operate with the tree structure to get the same result, you can split the problem in two parts: first find the shallowest node which is not complete, then add a new node to it. This is one way to do that:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.right_child = None
        self.left_child = None
        self.parent = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, value):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(value)
        else:
            # Find shallowest incomplete node (ignore returned depth)
            node, _ = Tree._next_insertion_node(self.root)
            # Add new node to it
            if node.left_child is None:
                node.left_child = Node(value)
            else:
                node.right_child = Node(value)

    @staticmethod
    def _next_insertion_node(node, level=0):
        # Returns shallowest incomplete node and its depth
        if node.left_child is None or node.right_child is None:
            return node, level
        node_left, level_left = Tree._next_insertion_node(node.left_child, level + 1)
        node_right, level_right = Tree._next_insertion_node(node.right_child, level + 1)
        if level_left <= level_right:
            return node_left, level_left
        else:
            return node_right, level_right

    def print(self):
        Tree._print_node(self.root)

    @staticmethod
    def _print_node(node, level=0):
        if node is None: return
        print(' ' * (level * 2), '*', node.value)
        Tree._print_node(node.left_child, level + 1)
        Tree._print_node(node.right_child, level + 1)

numbers = [12, 5, 18, 2, 9 , 15, 19, 13, 17]
tree = Tree()
for number in numbers:
    tree.insert(number)
tree.print()
# * 12
#   * 5
#     * 2
#       * 13
#       * 17
#     * 9
#   * 18
#     * 15
#     * 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way of doing it but I tried to write something similar to the approach you tried. Instead of immediately going to the left node, we record both nodes, and then iterate through in order that we've seen them. So first the root, then root.left, root.right, root.left.left, root.left.right, root.right.left ... etc

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.right_child = None
        self.left_child = None
        self.parent = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    # record nodes that need processing.
    nodes_to_process = []

    def insert(self,value):
        if(self.root==None):
            self.root=Node(value)
        else:
            # add the node to be processed
            self.nodes_to_process.append(self.root)
            self._insert(value)

    def _insert(self,value):
        # the current node is the next node in the list.
        curNode = self.nodes_to_process[0]

        if(curNode.left_child==None):
            curNode.left_child=Node(value)
            curNode.left_child.parent = curNode
            # reset the list, since we've inserted.
            self.nodes_to_process = []

        elif(curNode.right_child==None):
            curNode.right_child=Node(value)    
            curNode.right_child.parent = curNode   
            # reset the list, since we've inserted.
            self.nodes_to_process = []

        else:
            # insert the two child nodes.
            self.nodes_to_process.append(curNode.left_child)
            self.nodes_to_process.append(curNode.right_child)
            # Remove the node we've just examined.
            self.nodes_to_process.pop(0)
            self._insert(value)
```

Here's a quick test.

```py
tree = Tree()        

for number in [12, 5, 18, 2, 9 , 15, 19, 13, 17]:
    tree.insert(number)

print(tree.root.value) # 12
print(tree.root.left_child.value) #5
print(tree.root.left_child.left_child.value) # 2
print(tree.root.left_child.left_child.left_child.value) # 13
print(tree.root.left_child.left_child.right_child.value) # 17
```